# Why is razor code in VS19 not highlighting in .cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, v16.11.8 Preview 1.0 to work on MVC projects. At some point my razor code stopped appearing highlighted in `.cshtml` files, making HTML and C# difficult to tell apart. This is how the code looks now:
[image]

I've checked over the color settings for razor code by going to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> HTML Razor Code Background`, but this and the other related settings looked fine. I've also tried restarting VS and the machine itself.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. An experimental Razor editor is enabled by default in the preview. One of the [known issues](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-experimental-razor-editor-for-visual-studio/#known-issues) relates to the coloring.

To disable the experimental editor go to *Tools > Options > Preview Features* and scroll down to uncheck *Enable Experimental Razor editor (requires restart)*. Click Ok and restart your VS.

[image]